# How to fix this ajax request to stop failing in MVC5

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I'm the similar ajax requests to get other database info working. Perhaps its something minor that is causing the issue. Each time I execute this function it fails and throws the alert.

It is returning the 13 user records stored in my database, during debugging I can see that these 13 records are all correct.

My dissertation is due on Friday, so any help with this would be much appreciated.

```
 function FetchUsers() {
                userinfo = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET", url: "/home/GetUsers",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            userinfo.push({
                                usersId: v.UserID,
                                username: v.Username,
                            });
                        })
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('failed - error 01.000x unable to load users');
                    }
                })
            }
```

```
        public JsonResult GetUsers()
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities1 dc = new MyDatabaseEntities1())
            {
                var users = dc.Users.ToList();

                return new JsonResult { Data = users, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @RaviMathpal i'm not receiving an error when debugging. Visual stuido didn't throw an exceptions and the values looked fine when debugging, is possible to find out why it wasn't successful.